# MBProgress hud not showing Labeltext

Tags: objective-c, label, mbprogresshud

I wan't to show Progress indicator (MBprogress hud), here's the code i implemented.

```
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(showMe) toTarget:self withObject:NULL];
```

in show method , i have (tried to) displayed MBprogress Hud but it is not showing label text.

```
 -(void)showMe
{
 if(hudForBal) // hudForBal is my MBprogressHud's object
  {
    [hudForBal removeFromSuperview];
    [hudForBal release];
    hudForBal = nil;
   }

   hudForBal =[[MBProgressHUD alloc]init];
   hudForBal.labelText =@"Please wait...";
    hudForBal.delegate = Nil;
    [self.view addSubview:hudForBal];
   [hudForBal show:YES];
}
```

it is working but it is not showing label text .What am i doing wrong?
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't ui related stuff always be done in/on the main thread?

Comment: try hudForBal.delegate = Self may be thats y its not changing your label text

Comment: Tried that 'obvious' thing. @jayrajm.g.

Comment: I tried your same code in my file its working great..

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create a new thread to do this, in fact, making changes to the UI on any thread other than the main thread is undefined behavior. If you're already on the main thread when you would be calling this method, then all you have to do is perform the selector as you normally would, without sending it to a different thread.

However, if you're already on a background thread when you would be performing this selector, and you want to update the UI, you can use `dispatch_async()` as a quick and easy way to move back to the main thread.

```
- (void)showMe {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(hudForBal) {
            [hudForBal removeFromSuperview];
            [hudForBal release];
            hudForBal = nil;
        }

        hudForBal =[[MBProgressHUD alloc]init];
        hudForBal.labelText =@"Please wait...";
        hudForBal.delegate = Nil;
        [self.view addSubview:hudForBal];
        [hudForBal show:YES];
    });
}
```

Comment: depending on what your app is doing = is it maybe blocking the runloop,you may give the UI some time to update. From mac OS apps I know that sometimes it helps to do `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalFromNow:0.1];` just after setting the labelText or the show:Yes in your case.